# Echad Ve'arba'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred forty-one?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

141 is the [floor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) of the greatest distance (141 and a third, in cubits) two cities can be to view them as one (**sort of**: see *mishnayos Eruvin* chapter 5).

Answer (score 3):

141 years ago (Nov. 9, 1869) the Austro-Hungarian emperor Franz Joseph visited Jerusalem. Among the benefits to the Jewish People from his visit: a donation towards the completion of one of the Old City's famous shuls, Tiferes Yisrael (now, unfortunately, destroyed).

Answer (score 3):

141 is how many judges the great sanhedrin obviously doesn't need. (Source: *Bavli*, *Sanhedrin* 3b.)

Comment: ...which is also true of the numbers 16, 571, 4237½, and √π. Though it is true that the Gemara doesn't mention those as possibilities. :)

Answer (score 0):

Mitzva   =   141